# ViewStub'parent viewgroup

Tags: android, viewstub

What is the meaning of that exception

ava.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewStub must have a non-null ViewGroup viewParent

i am creating an array of View Stub and adding them to a linearLayout but this exception is showing at run time

```
for(int i=0;i&lt;1;i++)
{
  try
     {
       stub[0]=new ViewStub(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.view_stub_layout);

      //Viewv=stub[i].inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.view_stub_layout,mainLayout);
      //stub[0].setLayoutResource(R.layout.view_stub_layout);
      View v;
      v=stub[0].inflate();
      mainLayout.addView(v);
      v=null;
  }
  catch(Exception e){
      e.getMessage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ViewStub` don't have a parent, that's why you catch Exception. You must add `ViewStub` in `Layout` at first, after you can inflate it to another `View`.

Why you use `ViewStub`? Do you really need it? Maybe it can be good solution:

```
try {
    View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.view_stub_layout, mainLayout);
} catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
}
```

If you need to keep added Views:

```
try {
    views[i] = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.view_stub_layout, null);
    mainLayout.add(views[i]);
} catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
}
```