# ViewStub parent goes null

Tags: android, android-inflate, viewstub

I have a ViewHolder that contains a `ViewStub`, when I want to bind data into my view, I first check that is `viewStub` inflated before or not?

```
if (mViewStub != null) //still not inflated
```

then if `mViewStub` still not inflated, I try to inflate this by:

```
LinearLayout root = ((LinearLayout) mViewStub.inflate());
```

but here I get Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewStub must have a non-null ViewGroup viewParent

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13972321/7135845) and found that this exception will be thrown when the parent of ViewStub is null. By debugging, I find that it's true and the parent of my `mViewStub` was null.

the xml file is simple like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/root_view"
     android:layout_width="60dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/view_cell_stub"
        android:layout="@layout/item_card"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I must mention that `ViewStub` object does not create in runtime and I just find that by Id in ViewHolder class.

```
ViewStub mViewStub = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_cell_stub);
```

Finally, after this explanation, my main question is "why the parent of `mViewStub` goes null"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the source code of `ViewStub` from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/ViewStub.java) and I found this exception only be thrown when the parent is null or parent is not an instance of ViewGroup.

So I reviewed my code again and I found that when I inflate the XML and pass the view to the viewHolder, still view not have been added to root so the parent is null.

I have been forced to replace ViewStub with the custom layout that I implement by myself.